# crystal report problem

Tags: asp.net

On buttons selected index change i have generated a report, report's first page  it displayed proper with correct result but when i navigate to second page crystal report disappears  what is the reason  please let me know

> protected void
>   studentList_SelectedIndexChanged(object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           int studentId = Convert.ToInt32(studentList.SelectedValue);
>           ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
>           report.Load(Server.MapPath("StudentResume.rpt"));
>           DataTable tbl_students;
>           tbl_students = resumeManager.GetStudentListForCrystalRpt(studentId);
>           report.SetDataSource(tbl_students);
>           studentResumeCrViwer.ReportSource =
>   report;
>           // studentResumeCrViwer.
>       }

Comment: please give a heed to my problem too, it's been so long i am seeing to resolve my problem but i am not finding a proper solutions..please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the report viewer on the same page? I got a similar issue where I did the report binding in the page_load and on click of the page navigation, the page reloads forcing the navigation to fail. Moving the binding to the page_init solved the issue. Here also, I see that the page is reloaded and the viewer goes away.

Comment: yes i have the report viewer on the same page can u tell me how to resolve issue.. i really need to rebind it because on page navigation report is post back ...so where should i rebind it..

Comment: Actually rebinding loses the page navigation. Can you keep the binding info and bind it in the page_init? Like on the event, you might actually post the binding source back to the code behind and in the page_init event, bind the report source.

Comment: i did the same but it's of no avail please resolve my problem